# Call a function when the Python process gets terminated using Task Manager in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm working on a GUI application which lets you configure some options. When you close the application using the buttons on GUI, the program saves the configuration to a database file.

I'm using the `atexit` module for this task:

```py
import atexit

def on_exit():
    print("Exiting...")
    # Save to a database

atexit.register(on_exit)
```

However, the function doesn't get called when I terminate the Python process using Task Manager. I don't clearly know how Task Manager terminates processes, but is it possible to do the same thing for terminations made with Task Manager in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Task Manager terminates processes. It's likely to send one of two signals - either SIGTERM or SIGKILL.

If it's the former then you can set a handler for that. See [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)

If it's the latter, then you can't do anything about it

Comment: It looks like it uses SIGKILL. SIGTERM didn't work.

Comment: For the sake of completeness you could also try catching SIGINT but I suspect you're right about SIGKILL in which case, as I've already stated, you can't catch that

Comment: I've tried SIGINT too, didn't work either. Thanks anyway.